# kendoAutoComplete with Treeview structure data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown, kendo-autocomplete

I want to achieve kendoAutoComplete with Treeview structure data.
kendoDropDownTree works properly but I need the behavior exactly like kendoAutoComplete. I want to type in input control and value should be filtered.

kendoAutoComplete works fine with single value collection not with tree view structure.

Below is my sample datasource:

```
[
                {
                    "text": "Furniture", expanded: true, "items": [
                        { "text": "Tables & Chairs" },
                        { "text": "Sofas" },
                        { "text": "Occasional Furniture" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "text": "Decor", "items": [
                        { "text": "Bed Linen" },
                        { "text": "Curtains & Blinds" },
                        { "text": "Carpets" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

It would be helpful if somebody suggest how to proceed on this.

Comment: And you want to use all `text` properties, only nested `text` properties? Also, is there a limit of levels or that structure can have more levels... please explain more.

Comment: I want all the text properties (including parent, child). Extract Tree view structure. Limit may go up to 10 levels. I will auto select either Parent, Child